# .NET and Oracle: Joining a table to an empty set of another table

Tags: .net, sql, join, oracle9i

I am trying to join tableA with some data to an empty set of another tableB. The main purpose is to get all the columns of tableB. I do not need any data of tableB.

I have constucted the following SQL:

```
SELECT uar.*, s.screen_id, s.screen_name
FROM crs_screens 
 LEFT JOIN crs\_user\_access\_right uar
 ON s.rid IS NOT NULL AND uar.rid IS NULL
```

This SQL runs perfectly on TOAD but it returns an error when I use it in my VB.NET OracleDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable) statement.

It is fine if there is a work-around to achieve same effect. Thank you very much.

---

Error message:

> OCI-22060: argument [2] is an invalid or uninitialized number

---

Config:

.NET framework: 1.1

Oracle 9i

Comment: Does the stored proc have an out parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the problem is not with the statement, but something about the 2nd column of the "uar" table.
Can you try the query with a different table to confirm this?

Answer (score 0):

Try listing out all your columns explicitly and review all the data types - particular the second column of uar.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with Oracle (so I can't say if it is an Oracle issue specifically), but perhaps rephrasing your SQL like this would work:

```
SELECT
  uar.*, s.screen_id, s.screen_name
FROM 
  crs_screen s 
    LEFT JOIN crs_user_access_right uar ON uar.rid <> uar.rid
```

You shouldn't need the comparison on s.rid, since being on the left side, crs_screen will always be included in the left outer join.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of the client driver are you running? By that I mean the actual full version. For instance, if you're using OleDB to talk to Oracle, the version of the ORAOLEDB.DLL file. For instance, is it 9.2.0.7?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but if anyone else is having the "OCI-22060: argument [2] is an invalid or uninitialized number" issue, I've found a solution that works for me.

for the original cursor:

```
select l.t_id, r.t_name, r.t_desc
left_table l left join right_table r
on r.t_id = l.t_id;
```

... a simple refactor of ...

```
select -99999999 t_id, 'XXXXXXXXX' t_name, 'YYYYYYYYYYYY' t_desc from dual
union all
select l.t_id, r.t_name, r.t_desc
left_table l left join right_table r
on r.t_id = l.t_id;
```

... works.  I just had to filter out the bogus row in my client.